# Is it possible to ride on windsurfing inside tube (tubular wave)?

Tags: surfing, windsurfing

Surfing inside [a tube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surfing#Surf_waves) ["is surfing’s single greatest act; the supreme maneuver, the ultimate conquest.](http://www.surfoutlet.com/guides/how-to-tube-ride-in-surfing)" Can it be done using windsuring (= board with rig) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible : [A windsurfer getting barreled? kai_lenny making it happen for the first time at Pe’ahi!](https://www.facebook.com/aerialvideomaui/?__tn__=kC-R&eid=ARDuS5DIH2JsE3w0SC45uiEGIprygjn5Wb4Ea16xapBF1U9pq-DwN_F6DXvVUizA7teLjTAPIUhL7OJB&hc_ref=ARSndn1vC9ww0c-pkGO45ftMwQ9lb_G6pucYvsAvhvAlWk2PEfwzP4ndK48_I8nHdFU&fref=nf&__xts__%5B0%5D=68.ARAXLdhjK8x4O9PdR8Qd1R-KLZhSHHhGY28iwrXuVA3IN1X5JAEoR1ExjlZz4RB8gaiCVC31UGRJaSYJ7OgSBiqBAq6XT3maBhaS9_OkfrlcCmtHchg96HEEj6v3NIoHp99UQYpMGvg_7OS3cB-OITxHC3xCG03G6jlsbyLRu3GA6E3ZJcd1KNJodiwPU60GZTTQamimf3Gk3tUN8cUhyzs_vqZ3J-kACkUnoebJ-Tll3WidsZu0Si7nMZhei4REh8-jRrO4dUQlzbJ388DhC2KuwpEaYjmvs1FjwbtCSH9sshpuCfLR-cVHI_bCFUNZqBdWTngWqE83ZiPZ-d-HVVeq2Fqy4Y8CPZYAOw)

Answer (score 0):

It's practically impossible. I don't think one could find a perfect wave with a perfect running tube big enough to cover your rig. Besides that a windsurfer won't be able to control velocity, balance and projection (critical for that insane tube riding) inside a huge tube like that.